# XPath: opposite of string() function?

Tags: xpath

In XPath it is possible to convert an object to string using the [string() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-string). Now I want to convert the string back to an object.

I do understand it is not possible in some cases (for example for elements), because some information was lost. But it should be possible for simple types, like int or boolean.

I know, for numbers I can use `number()` function, but I want general mechanism which will work for any simple type variable.

Answer (score 4):

Going to `string` is easy, because you've told it that you want a string.

Similarly, going to `number` is easy, because you've told it that you want a number.

But there is no generic way to say 'turn it back into *x*', because you haven't told it what *x* is.

(In other words, string() is like a `cast` like Java/C/C++/C# have. But there is no `uncast`.)

string() isn't an object serializer, so you can't deserialize.

Why do you want this? Perhaps there is another way of solving your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delays in response... What I acctually need is simple-type serialization (well, serialization is easy) and deserialization, but of course I know the actual type of variable I'm going to construct! :)

It seems the problem is not about XPath either :) I've just used BPEL <copy><from>xpath</from><to>myvariable</to></copy> construction, where myvariable is of right type, and this works fine

Answer (score 2):

If your object `$x` is the number `1234`, then `string($x)` will be the string `"1234"`.

If your object `$x` is a nodeset of 1000 XML elements, the first one being

```
<wibble><wobble>1<ping/>2</wobble>34</wibble>
```

then `string($x)` will be the string `"1234"`.

The function is not a bijection, you can't have an inverse as many different values map to the same string.

Answer (score 0):

In no language (that I know of) you can cast A to B and then call a magical function that reverts it back to whatever it was before you casted it.

The process of converting some data type into something else is always an unidirectional one - you lose the information what type it was *before*. That's because the new data type has *no way of storing* what it was before.

So, what are you trying to do? I strongly suspect that you ask this question because you are tackling a problem from the wrong end.

Comment: Agree, but if you know the type, you can often cast back. for example: (Circle) figure.